# Play 1000 FPS Video at 1000 FPS

Tags: video, playback

I tried to play 1000fps video on vlc, google drive,etc but the irregularity in the playback is quite visible and sometimes the video gets stuck. Kindly help me out if there is a software/server where it can be played smoothly.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'd say hardware is going to be your biggest obstacle to playing anything at 1000fps, that and the fact that it won't be humanly possible to tell if you're dropping frames.

Answer (score 2):

Since there aren't any monitors that I'm aware of that display 1000 frames per second, I assume you want to play back for viewing in realtime, but don't care about the lost data.  The trick of 1000fps video is that the amount of data is pretty staggering.  If the resolution is pretty limited, it might be doable on non-specialized hardware, but data rate is most likely your enemy here and is probably why you are having issues.

Your best bet is going to be to transcode in to a proxy file that is a more reasonable framerate for viewing.  This will allow you to easily view the file in realtime without losing any information that you wouldn't already be losing due to the screen you are watching it on.

Answer (score 0):

Try ffplay, but you must have proper device for playback. Unfortunately, current monitors can show only 60 fps. Some old CRT monitors can display upto 120 fps.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Very many modern monitors can show upwards of 60fps, though still not 1000.

Comment: If the output is preserving realtime playback, and dropped frames are ok, then ffplay can do it. Add `-vf fps=60`.